# Can't use domain credentials, but server is part of the domain

Tags: domain-controller, ms-office-communicator, credentials

I have added a server to my domain, but the domain credentials don't work on the server even though it offers the domain at login. The server has an entry in the AD, DNS, and DCHP; any suggestions?

All servers in the domain are running Win 2003 R2 x64. The server in question is an Edge server in a deployment of OCS 2007 Standard edition R2.

EDIT:
Solution - Removed and reconnected it to the domain a few times, seems to have worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the server is edge, chances are it's out in your DMZ. You'll need to ensure that there's sufficient rules punched between the server and its domain controller, through the firewall.

If possible look at firewall traffic logs between that server and the DCs, and you should find some dropped traffic.

Answer (score 1):

When I had a somewhat similar problem I used Wireshark to watch the traffic, which made me realise I had neglected to open one of the ports from the DMZ to the internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the server time is not more than 5 minutes behind/ahead domain time.
It must have an AD Dns server as primary dns server

Answer (score 0):

Is the computer account valid?